# Parameter missing a value

Tags: reporting-services

I am new to reporting services and have a reporting services 2005 report that I am working on to use as a base report template for our organization.  I am trying to place the date that the report was last modified on the report server into the page header of the report. However, I keep getting a 'ParamX' parameter is missing a value error when I try to  This is what I have done:

Set up a Parameter ReportName with a default value of Globals!ReportName.  It is also hidden and internal.

Set up a Dataset ReportHeader that calls a stored procedure that returns the date the report was last updated or another date, if the report is not on the report server.  It has a parameter @ReportName assigned to the Parameter!ReportName.Value.  The Dataset returns values when run on the dataset tab in the BI tool.

Set up a Parameter ReportVersion that has a default value Query From based on the dataset ReportHeader and picking the ModDate column. It is the last parameter in the report parameters list.

I assign a textbox to the parameter.

When I preview, I get "The 'ReportVersion' parameter is missing a value whether I place it in the report body or page header (which is where I want it).  I have deleted and added the parameter again, toyed with the hidden and internal settings on it.

What does this error really mean, what I am missing, and can I even do this with parameters?

Thanks In Advance

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing, it sounds like you want to be using a field where you're implementing a parameter...

You are returning the ModDate from the data source, correct? If you're doing this, you can simply throw a text box in there, and use something like this: =Fields!modDate.Value to display it.

Parameters are values that go in to the query, fields are what it returns.

Hope this helps...

EDIT:: OK so are you trying to retrieve the mod-date column value from the reportserver db? If that's what we're talking about, you'll need to add a few things to the report. Add a datasource to report db, a dataset containing the date (query below), a list object in the report linked to the dataset, and a textbox in said list object to display the field. If you hit the report server with a query like this:

```
SELECT MAX(ModifiedDate) AS ModDate FROM catalog WHERE name='myReportName'
```

That will return your modifieddate from the ReportSErvices Database as a field that you can use.

Comment: sort of.  I since I want to use the dataset values (or really data from the report server) in the page header, but, can't due to reporting service limitations, I was trying to populate the parameter with the dataset return value and then put it in the header. Is there another way to get around this limitation.  thanks.

Comment: thanks.  I checked the fields for the dataset in the body of the report and found that were not displaying data either, so, I redid the data source.  I think the credentials might have gotten goofed up (as that created a similar error on subsequent testing), but I did not pay close enough attention before I redid the data source.  Now the process works as expected.  thanks again for your help.